# Auto size column width for Flexigrid

Tags: jquery, flexigrid

Is it possible to have the width set automatically to the full width of the Flexigrid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in JavaScript. When setting the width, instead of using a number use a function that's defined in JS to calculate the widths of the columns based on percentage.

Comment: how did you achieve the auto full width?

Comment: can you please share, how did you achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

Try not defining the width of Flexigrid